# Jmeter Mobile App testing - Unable to proxy

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Installed Jmeter 5.3 on my Mac. I had set the HTTP(s) proxy to 8089. Installed Jmeter certificate on my pixel 2xl device. Configured the proxy with port. After proxy setup, unable to surf internet on my mobile. As a result unable to record Jmeter script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that both devices are on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and you can i.e. ping mobile from laptop and vice versa
2. Make sure that JMeter is listening to IPv4 interface and if this is not the case - add `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
3. Make sure that incoming connections to port 8089 are not blocked by your [operating system firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) or other antivirus software
4. If your device is running [Android 7.0](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) or higher you need to take some extra steps to be able to record HTTPS traffic, in particular:

   - Add the next line to the [`application` section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) of your [Android application  manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) file:

     ```
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
     ```
   - Create `network_security_config.xml` file under your [application resources folder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and put the following code inside:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <network-security-config>
         <debug-overrides>
             <trust-anchors>
                 <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
                 <certificates src="user" />
             </trust-anchors>
         </debug-overrides>
     </network-security-config>
     ```
   - Compile and install your application in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode):

     ```
     gradlew installDebug
     ```

   More information: [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)

If you don't have access to application sources you will have to [root your device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android)) in order to be able to record traffic using JMeter by placing its certificate into Android OS  trusted authorities storage

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Forget about the app, the moment i keep my mobile device on proxy, unable to surf anything thru browser. In jmeter ViewResultTree, i see this response "avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake"